# How to use Tor "on" and "off" at the same time with Chrome?

Tags: chrome

I want to use both Tor "on" and "off" in chrome. As for example one tab of chrome with tor "on", and another tab or directory of it as "off".
Is it possible?

Comment: This isn't currently possible, and I don't think it'd be a good idea. Allowing the functionality that you describe would leave too much chance for human error when switching between tabs. For users whose anonymity is essential to their wellbeing, this sort of functionality would be a nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: Prett sure this should just be the answer, not a comment :P